# Make recursion more efficient in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I have written the following recursion in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 100
using namespace std;


long long int recursion(int array[], int begin,int end, long long int now){
    if(now>N){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        long long int huge_number=N/now;
        for(int i=1;i<end-begin;i++){
            huge_number=huge_number-recursion(array,begin+i,end,now*array[begin+i]);
        }
        return huge_number;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int array[4]={2,3,5,7};
    /*FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("primes.txt","r");
    for(int i=0;i<78498;i++){
        fscanf(pFile, "%d", &priemen[i]);
    }
    fclose(pFile);*/ 
    //I have actually a txt file with primes less than 10^6
    int number_divisible[4];//this array will contain the desired numbers as explained below
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        number_divisible[i]=N/array[i];
        for(int j=0; j<i;j++){
            number_divisible[i]=number_divisible[i]-recursion(array,j,i,array[i]*array[j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code does the following: take for example N=100. The array will consist of prime numbers up to the square root of N, so array={2,3,5,7}. With this recursion we can calculate how much numbers between 2 and 100 are multiples of a prime p in {2,3,5,7} but not a multiple of primes less than p.

If I want to use this for huge numbers N, say 10^9, then it takes too much time for the program to complete.

**My question is whether we can optimise the code given above.** If not, then I have to find a different algorithm for computing the desired numbers explained above.

Comment: The code as written does not compile.  Can you include a definition of `N`?  Is it a constant?

Comment: @Yakk , I am sorry, but I did not include all of the code so that you can compile it. I will edit my question and add the necessary code.

Comment: Make it minimal.  Ideally you should be able to copy-paste the code and it will run and generate an output.  This should require at most 10 more lines of code than what you have above...  Aside: you never access `array[0]`.  That seems to disagree with your definition of the algorithm.

Comment: Make it non-recursive.  With a simple recursion like this you can get the same behavior with a loop.

Comment: Your title is misleading, as your question is much more specific than optimising recursion. Moreover, you haven't shown any effort toward finding answer yourself.

Comment: Where is this `prime p` from your description? Like with most performance-related questions, where is the hotspot when you run it in a profiler?

Comment: You can have a look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27449650/3723423)

Comment: Do you want to optimize the code (implementation) or the algorithm?

Comment: You shouldn't care about recursion performance. You need a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: You might want to learn about dynamic programming: http://qr.ae/R2FpbQ

Answer (score 2):

One way to improve recursion performance is to reduce the number of parameters to the bare minimum needed.

Another way is to replace recursion with iteration.  This requires algorithmic analysis or insight.

Yet another way is to reduce the levels of recursion.  This also requires analysis and insight.

After a glance at your code, it does look like it is ripe for iterative replacement by adding an array to track previously calculated values.